# Overriding plugin behaviour in SonarQube 4.0

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of the `NewIssuesEmailTemplate` in `SonarQube 4.0`. I want to put richer information into the generated emails. It looks as if everything I need is put in the Notification by `IssueNotifications`.

What I want to know is if it's possible to override the fact that `NewIssuesEmailTemplate` is the handler for Notifications of type `"new-issues"`.

I'm going to hazard that this can be done by creating a new plugin that overrides the specific behaviour of `CorePlugin`, and making sure that this gets loaded first, but I don't really know how to go about it.

Has anyone done anything like this before? I don't seem to be able to find any hints to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the fact that `NewIssuesEmailTemplate` is the handler for notifications of type "`new-issues`".

All you can do is to add new channels or dispatchers using the extensions available in the [notification API](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/notifications). You can check how this is done by the [Core Email plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/plugins/sonar-email-notifications-plugin).